# Manipulating a .replace() match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text string like this:

```
1398097442.61 INFO Some Name: Some Thing ...9381
```

I want to convert the number at the beginning into a human readable datetime.

What I'm doing is this:

```
input.replace(/^(\d+\.?\d*)/g, new Date(parseFloat("$1") * 1000).toGMTString());
```

This doesn't work. If I were to just reprint the match "$1" that's fine. How can I manipulate the match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure you are passing a function to replace (after all, this isn't Scala) :-)

```
input.replace(/^(\d+\.?\d*)/g, function(match, timestamp) {
 return new Date(parseFloat(timestamp) * 1000).toGMTString();
});
```

The way you *were* doing it created a date from the result of calling `parseFloat` on the string "$1" and then took the result (`NaN`) and passed it of to the `Date` constructor and got out a GMT string - which was then used as the replacement string for your regular expression.

What you *want* to do is defer the execution of the `new Date` code until you have a match. Since [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can take a function as it's second argument, we can just wrap the `new Date` behavior in a function and everything will just work.

Answer (score 1):

You may need this:

```
var subject = "1398097442.61 INFO Some Name: Some Thing ...9381";
var date = new Date(parseFloat(subject.replace(/(\d+\.\d+)/g, "$1")) * 1000).toGMTString();
console.log(date);
```

***DEMO:***

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/xh2G6/